# I don't know local spatial correlation meaning

Tags: deep-learning, cnn

In [GoogLeNet paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842), 'local sparse correlation' is mentioned. But, I don't know the meaning. Also, I don't understand that statement " In the lower layers (the ones close to the input) correlated units would concentrate in local regions. This means,we would end up with a lot of clusters concentrated in a single region and they can be covered by a layer of 1×1 convolutions in the next layer"

Comment: Hi, can you link the paper?

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.4842